# Optimising C++ code block containing for and if

Tags: c++, function, loops, optimization

I'm working on a problem, and here's a piece of code that's working significantly worse than the theoretical expectation:

```
inline bool check(const int index, const float* f) const{
    for(int j=0; j<d; j++)
        if(points[index][j] != f[j])
            return false;
    return true;        
}

bool func(int p_cap, const float* f) const{
    int i = (p_cap - error > 0? p_cap - error: 0);
    int l = (p_cap + error + 1 < keyCount? p_cap + error + 1: keyCount);
    for(; i<l; i++)
        if(check(i, f))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

These functions are inside a class, with both `points` and `keyCount` being members of the class. `points` is a `keyCount*d` 2-dimensional array. `d` is a global variable. Any help on how can I possibly optimise this code block? Thanks...

**EDIT:**

I'm using interpolation for searching in the array, and my data is such that it is possible. The expectation is that it will be faster to search any point using this technique than linear search. The reason I have this expectation is because `error = 1`. This means, for any point, I'm looking at a maximum of `3` different points in the `points` array. I have a million such arrays. Each storing exactly 10 points. The expected value for linear search would be `N/2`, which means I'll need to look through `5` before I hit the query point (again, expected/average value). Thus, this "interpolation code" should run faster than the linear search, but that's not happening.

Compilation command used:

```
g++ -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG test.cpp -o test
```

Comment: What is the value of `d`?

Comment: And what's the theoretical expectation?

Comment: No size checking in `check()`, nice. If you have any expectation other than O(n), you're dreaming. It looks like you have to inspect the entire array in the worst case. You also don't show how you're measuring, what your expectation is, etc. The only way to get faster is to sort the array if possible and implement a faster search.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie d is usually either 2 or 3

Comment: @bipll I'm using interpolation to search in an array, and expected in to be better than linear search

Comment: The test `if(points[index][j] != f[j])` in `check` looks a bit suspicious.  Are you really comparing floats like that?  It will almost always be true meaning `check` will return false and the loop in `func` will never finish early.  i.e. all `l` iterations will run.  I'd naively expect `func` to be O(N) w.r.t `l`.

Comment: @sweenish error is 1. `const int` declared initially. I wrote about interpolation in previous comment. There are *never* more than 3 checks (that assuming the array in searchable using interpolation, which is true for my data)

Comment: @G.M. I'm reading those from a file. Both points and f. There are no calculations involved whatsoever involving either of `points` or `f`. Hence, no issue in comparing like this

Comment: @AnkitKumar -- *here's a piece of code that's working significantly worse than the theoretical expectation:* -- So far, you've dismissed all of the comments about the code.  So what is *your* reason why you think it is "significantly worse?".  You're the best person to figure this out, since you have all of the code.  We have what you posted, which to me has linear complexity due to the `for` loop in  `func`.  Since you stated that `d` is only 2 or 3, the result is still linear.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've editted my code to address the issues your comment raised. Please look through it once to see if that's what you asked for

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations turned on?  You failed to mention the compiler options you're using.  And how are you measuring these minute differences?  You must have had a "good" run (according to what you're saying) to compare to.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie done

Comment: @AnkitKumar what do you mean by "using interpolation to search in an array"?

Comment: @bipll I have 2 end points of an array, working only on one axis. Using those, I can calculate the slope and base, thus the interpolation

Comment: @AnkitKumar except for there's nothing in your code about this fact. If every column of the array is indeed an arithmetic progression the the search can be done in O(1) and you need not to scan the whole column for an obvious value.

Comment: @bipll I did't include the interpolation related code. That's a simple multiplication and addition man! Nothing in that to optimise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the compiler already does this, but you can do 2 things:

- Loop through the arrays with 1 for loop (as C++ stores them sequentially in memory), this removes the need of several index and pointer calculations, though only if you want to loop through all entries and if all entries are checkable.
- Turn it into a single if check, in your example you are using 1 in the check() function and the returned value is being checked again in the func() function.

You would need to check the compiled code to see if it already applies these optimizations.

Comment: The first one is done by the compiler if you use different compiler flags (which I am using). Can you please elaborate on the second point?

Comment: @AnkitKumar your check() function is doing an if check per entry, then it returns a bool, this bool is then checked ("again in some way") in your func() function. In the end you can omit all func()'s if checks as these were already checked.

Comment: I tried what you're saying, and I was unable to do it without 2 for loops. Now with 2 for loops, I had to use `goto` statement, which I believe slow down the code a bit. Please correct me if I'm wrong, or please suggest a different method if you know?

Comment: hmm you would place the second for loop right under the first one, instead of using a separate function. Though I'm not sure if the compiler already does this optimization.

Comment: @AnkitKumar I'm getting different results depending on using the function check() vs inlining it manually, try it out: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: I'll look into it and let you know in an hour. Thank you